# How to use python files in src/package_name in nodes folder?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a catkin project in python.
I would like to put nodes in the "node" directory, and other source files in the src/package_name directory.
However when I did that and tried to import a python module in the node file (located in the node folder) from the source directory I got an error saying the module didn't exist.

I couldn't find any tutorials on how to do this.
Do I have to somehow tell catkin to export my src folder?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126926/how-to-use-python-files-in-src/package_name-in-nodes-folder?/) by [Vladimir](https://answers.ros.org/users/11706/vladimir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to create `setup.py`, and then add the `catkin_python_setup()` function to your `CMakeLists.txt`. A good example package to follow is [nmea_navsat_driver](https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver).

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-02-06**:
You will find further information here: http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/installing_python.html

**Comment by [Vladimir](https://answers.ros.org/users/11706/vladimir/) on 2014-02-06**:
Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2014-02-07**:
Dirk— askbot mangles links which are the end of comments. You can add trailing punctuation to fix it, eg:

http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/installing_python.html .